# Should we use DBI bind or place holder for one parameter

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a sql query like below

```
select id from table where name like 'somename';
```

Now there's only one record for this in db. Now with bind, sql query goes as below

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select id from table where name=?");
$sth->execute('somename');
.... # fetch single row from array
```

So which one is better? with bind or without for single row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Reason is very simple - using placeholders is good idea, and using it even for single argument makes it good practice. After some time, your hands will use placeholders even without thinking about it.

Comment: It also will prevent SQL injection, which is the same concern whether it's a large query or not.

Comment: It's good practice but will this be better in performance than sql without bind?

Comment: performance is a more complicated topic than "should i use placeholders or no". assuming everything else is the same, usually there shouldn't be speed difference.